# Javascript Filter With Multiple Options Not Displaying Results With ALL Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a javascript filter (multiple options) that gives users the option to filter Recipes by:

- Category
- Servings
- Cookingtime

When someone selects a filter from EACH of the 3 options, or 2 of the options, I want the results to only show recipes that contain **ALL** 3 options in them, or **ALL** 2 options.

Right now if multiple filters are selected, it'll show all results that have one of the filters, but not ALL that is selected.

This is the code I have:

```
filterRecipes: function() {
    $.each(this.recipes, function(index, recipe) {
      recipe.$el.show();
    });
    for(var filter in this.filters) {
      if(filter == 'category' && this.filters[filter].length > 0) {
        for(var i=0;i<this.recipes.length;i++) {
          if(this.filters[filter].indexOf(this.recipes[i].category) == -1) {
            this.recipes[i].$el.hide();
          } else {
            this.recipes[i].$el.show();
          }
        }
      }
      else if(filter == 'servings' && this.filters[filter].length > 0) {
        for(var i=0;i<this.recipes.length;i++) {
          if(this.filters[filter].indexOf(this.recipes[i].servings) == -1) {
            this.recipes[i].$el.hide();
          } else {
            this.recipes[i].$el.show();
          }
        }
      }
      else if(filter == 'cookingtime' && this.filters[filter].length > 0) {
        for(var i=0;i<this.recipes.length;i++) {
          if(this.filters[filter].indexOf(this.recipes[i].cookingtime) == -1) {
            this.recipes[i].$el.hide();
          } else {
            this.recipes[i].$el.show();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="recipe-search-results"></div>
<aside id="text-7" class="widget shadow widget_text">
<div class="textwidget" id="recipe-search-filters" style="padding: 10px;">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="category">Category</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="servings">Servings</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="cookingtime">cooking Time</label>
    </fieldset>
</aside>
</div>
</div>
```

Basically the filters need to work with eachother to show the results, rather than individually.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you also add the html? Makes it easier to debug

Comment: You can paste the rendered HTML